# what is the difference between QT-Embedded and QTopia?

Tags: qtembedded

I have seen so many documentation about QT Embedded and QTopia. But not clear about the difference. Can anybody please explain the differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Qtopia** uses a subset of Qt/Embedded. It's designed for handheld devices such as PDAs and cell phones. On some platforms, it also provides a special native look and feel to coincide with the PDA/cell phone/device.

**Qt/Embedded** is a more general purpose framework for embedded application development on various devices. It is often used in embedded Linux applications, where a full window manager etc. are not available. It has a smaller footprint than Qt but larger than Qtopia.

---

In order to decide which is better for your application, you should look at the libraries that are part of Qt/Embedded but not Qtopia. Also examine your system resources: the closer your system is to a normal desktop/laptop computer, the more likely Qt/Embedded is the choice. The closer you are to PDA or phone hardware, Qtopia is the likely candidate.

Comment: IIRC Qt/Embedded is being removed in favor of either Qt (now more modular) or Qtopia

Comment: Martin, I think you're correct on this one. I developed for embedded systems and we were simply using a subset of Qt libraries.